# How do I rotate the Android emulator display?

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

How can I rotate the Android emulator display to see it in landscape mode?

Comment: Things have changed quite a bit since this was asked, please see [this page](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html#tasks)

Answer (score 1200, accepted):

**Windows:** <kbd>left Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>

**Mac:** <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>

Comment: @Omar : According to the comment of the tutorial http://androidandme.com/2009/10/news/how-to-install-android-sdk-and-play-with-android-2-0-in-the-emulator/ , you can rotate on Mac with Shift + F12

Comment: Might be stupid but how to return this back to normal?!

Comment: For those wanting to figure out how to rotate again, you cannot simply keep holding control and then push F11 or F12.  You must release control from the prior key push prior to pushing Control F11 or F12 again.

Comment: Fn + Ctrl + F12, I really don't get why this get so many votes

Comment: For Kubuntu users, `Ctrl+F12` activates the Widget Dashboard. You will need to make sure `NUMLOCK` is off and press the `7` number key instead.

Comment: Well, this rotates the picture, but the android running in the VM does not detect the rotation an so everything is sideways. :/

Comment: These keystrokes just rotate what's shown (which is initially on its side for some bizarre reason)... but don't change the display aspect between landscape and portrait as when you rotate the phone.  I found choosing a QVGA rather than HVGA device makes the emulation come the right way up.

Comment: left Ctrl+F11 seems to work too.

Comment: Tryied it under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, works perfectly.

Comment: @panzi In my case the app wasn't rotating because I forgot to enable the Auto-Rotate feature from android settings

Comment: Its now CMD + <- or CMD + -> for Mac

Comment: If none of these work, just cold boot it

Comment: Is there a way other than keyboard shortcut? ... ctrl+f11 and ctrl+f12 don't work for me (on windows)

Answer (score 361):

- **Linux:** <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>
- **Mac:** <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>
- **Windows:** <kbd>Left CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>Left CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>

Comment: F11 or F12 alone did not work on windows

Comment: as mentioned by @ccheneson only left CTRL + F11 OR left CTRL F12 works for windows

Comment: For Mac use **Left Ctrl**.

Comment: CTRL + F12 works on ubuntu too.

Comment: Only Left CTRL + F11 or F12 button works in Windows.

Comment: I don't have **Right Ctrl** on my mac book :)

Comment: @E.Gunyar Updated answer accordingly.

Answer (score 52):

Turn off `NUMLOCK` and press <kbd>NUMPAD 9</kbd> to rotate the emulator.

Comment: For me, I did not have to turn the number pad off.  But, I did have to wait into the emulator was fully booted up before it started working.

Answer (score 40):

As far as I know, <kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd> doesn't work, and nor does <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>.

Hit <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>, or <kbd>Home</kbd>, or <kbd>PageUp</kbd>, (not <kbd>NUMPAD 7</kbd> or <kbd>NUMPAD 9</kbd> like [the website](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html) says) to rotate the emulator.

Comment: For me `NUMPAD 7` did the trick

Answer (score 37):

On Mac OS X, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> to rotate the Android emulator if you have have not configured your keyboard to "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys" (Check it on System Preferences - Keyboard).

If you have checked the option mentioned above, you will not need the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key and you should be able to rotate the emulator only with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>.

Answer (score 26):

If you're on a Mac, <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> will rotate the emulator.

But if you're using 4.4, that won't rotate the application orientation.  [There's a bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61671)

Comment: Ah, thanks for mentioning the bug on the 4.4 emulator - it had me thinking my code was buggy.

Comment: IMHO the mention about the 4.4 bug should should be in the main answer. This is top result in google, but it didnt answer me before i dug deeper in other answers and this one in particular!

Answer (score 22):

[Use NUMPAD 7 and NUMPAD 9](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html#controlling). It will help you.

Answer (score 16):

<kbd>NUMPAD 7</kbd> and <kbd>NUMPAD 9</kbd> work fine for me.

Comment: But not 8. And only if NumLock is off. Who's the clever twit at Google that decided to recognize numpad 7 (but not the 7 or Home keys) and numpad 9 (but not the 9 or PgUp keys), only if NumLock is off?!

Comment: On my computer with Numlock on, 9 both sends a "9" to the current program *and* rotates the emulator screen...  !

Answer (score 6):

**Device Start-up Configuration -- Via the GUI**

To **start-up** the device in Landscape mode, modifications be made in the Android Virtual Device (AVD) Manager. Open the Virtual Device Manager, and click the Edit pencil:

[image: AVD Manager]

Then, under Startup size and orientation, select Landscape:

[image: Configure AVD]

.. and click Finish.

**Device Start-up Configuration -- Via the config file**

Despite the seemingly easy way to configure this, in practice this didn't work for me. So there's a way to edit the device's configuration file instead to force it to start-up in Landscape mode.

It involves manually switching the width and height in the `hardware-qemui.ini` file.

To do so, open this file for edit in a text editor:

```
C:\Users\<user>\.android\avd\<deviceName>.avd\hardware-qemu.ini
```

Switch the values of the width and height, so that the width is longer than the height:

```
hw.lcd.width = 800
hw.lcd.height = 480
```

The AVD now boots in Landscape mode. The orientation may still be [changed with shortcut keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4535312/3063884).

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> did not work for me, nor did <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>PageUp</kbd> etc.

So here's what finally came up with:

- Enable `NUMLOCK`;
- Open your emulator and press the <kbd>7</kbd> followed by <kbd>9</kbd> on the NUMPAD on the right side of your keyboard;
- Now your emulator will be rotated in the opposite direction;

Answer (score 5):

For Mac you can use <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>Left control</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>.

Comment: For Mac: This didn't work for me, I used the Num Pad - 7 and Num Pad 9 which worked

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> works on Windows.

Answer (score 4):

Press <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>  to rotate the emulator view.

Note: Right Ctrl doesn't work;

Answer (score 2):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>. This will rotate your emulator.

Answer (score 2):

For rotating the emulator, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

For Linux the <kbd>F12</kbd> combination does not work. Instead, use:

<kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can use <kbd>Numpad-9</kbd>  and <kbd>Numpad-7</kbd> to rotate on **Windows** and **[Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29)**.

Answer (score 0):

[Ubuntu 12.10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_12.10_.28Quantal_Quetzal.29) (Quantal Quetzal): <kbd>[LEFT Ctrl]</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>.

For some reason <kbd>NumLock</kbd> isn't working on a new install on a [Dell XPS 8500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dell_XPS#XPS_8500), but the above worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked on Windows:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> both are working to change the orientation of the Android simulator.

For other shortcut keys:

In the [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) toolbar go to "Help-->key Assist.. "

You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>
here, so many shortcut keys of Eclipse are given.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac: **<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>**

On Linux: **<kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>**

If you want to rotate just the screen and not the emulator: **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>** (I tried it on Linux)

Answer (score 0):

On my DELL XPS ultrabook with Linux Mint 15, none of suggested methods work, until an external keyboard is plugged in and use  left <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>NUMPAD 9</kbd>.

Answer (score -1):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> to rotate the emulator screen.

Answer (score -6):

### Make sure that "Auto Rotate" on your Android settings is enabled

Press <kbd>F9</kbd>   two times in less than 2 seconds = Normal view 0/360º

Press <kbd>F10</kbd> two times in less than 2 seconds = Rotate 180º.

Press <kbd>F11</kbd>  two times in less than 2 seconds = Rotate 90º to the RiGHT.

Press <kbd>F12</kbd> two times in less than 2 seconds = Rotate 90º to the LEFT.