# Wrong display direction AVD Manager

Tags: android, android-emulator

When I start a Virtual device older than 4.2.2 version ... the display it is something like the picture....

What I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try rotating with the Keyboard Commands for the emulator:

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html#KeyMapping

Or

Check [How do I rotate the Android emulator display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535298/how-to-rotate-the-android-emulator-display?rq=1)

UPDATE:

I've investigated a bit. It's probably a ROM / system library bug, not an emulator bug, since it happens on real phones too.

UPDATE2:

Why don't you post it as an Android issue in their site https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?

Comment: No it's not a simple rotation (I hav try it). If you can see on the image the menu is down and all others is like work as land :/