# Forcibly run android emulator in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-emulator

I need to run emulator with size 1366x768 in landscape mode. But when I launch emulator, it automatically changes into portrait mode, but with same scale (height is 1366, width is 768, but I need otherwise). So, changing mode by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> don't helps, because after changes, proportions stay the same. Any suggestion?

Comment: how about using geny-motion, it supports rotation ! :)

Comment: didn't here about it, will have to try

Comment: http://www.genymotion.com/

Comment: Press Number "9" from your right pane of keyboard.

Comment: Sorry, don't get it. Where and when should i press 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try Genymotion, fast, supports rotation and sensors too.

http://www.genymotion.com/

Answer (score 1):

**For Windows OS:**

Run your emulator and press **Number 9**.By pressing **Number "9"**. You can toggle from landscape to portrait and portrait to landscape.  I hope you get it now. Here is an image which **Number 9** you need to press:

[image]

**For Linux:**

You should use **Left Ctrl** + **F12**. It'll work for sure.

*I am not sure about this, But you can try.* **Use NUMPAD 7 followed by NUMPAD 9.**

For more information , [Go Here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html#KeyMapping)

Also You need to see [**This link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535298/how-to-rotate-the-android-emulator-display)

Let me know if it helped. **Thanks.**

Comment: You might need to accept any as an answer, If any is working for you.

Comment: I didn't find any solution for emulator, so i installed genimotion. But thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

To force landscape mode boot-up, edit the device's configuration file to force the height and width settings.

Open this file for edit in a text editor:

```
C:\Users\<user>\.android\avd\<deviceName>.avd\hardware-qemu.ini
```

Switch the values of the width and height, so that the width is longer than the height:

```
hw.lcd.width = 800
hw.lcd.height = 480
```

The AVD now boots in Landscape mode. The orientation may still be [changed with shortcut keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4535312/3063884).