# Android Emulator Screen Upside Down

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

My Android Virtual Device Emulator seems to be showing my screen upside down. Like So:

[image]

This is the device configuration:
[image]

I have tried unchecking the "Use Host GPU", as mentioned in other post, to no result.

I have also tried changing the orientation from "portrait" to "sensorPortrait", like mentioned in some other post. Again no result.

Please give a solution to this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535298/how-to-rotate-the-android-emulator-display

Comment: again, my problem is not portrait or landscape, as you can see it is totally upside down, i need to reverse it. Pressing ctrl+F11 or F12, does not reverse, it just switches from landscape to portrait and vica versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the skin type on device configuration, try to restart Virtual Device Emulator .