# How to rotate camera on android studio into potrait mode

Tags: android-studio, flutter, camera, rotation

I am building flutter apps and using access to camera, when I try camera emulator from android studio, it always in landscape mode, is there a way to set it in potrait mode ?

Comment: You mean, the emulator is in landscape mode? Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4535315/192373)

Comment: the emulator is in potrait position, but when I open camera of emulator, it came out in landscape

Comment: You mean, you take a picture, and the Jpeg is landscape? This is by design, and applies the overwhelming majority of physical devices, as well. You may find an orientation flag in the image EXIF header.

Comment: Generally speaking, it is not recommended to base your development on the emulator camera, but rather work with a physical device; probably, more than one device – camera behavior may differ significantly between manufacturers and device models.

Comment: @AlexCohn thank you for your suggestion and information, I will try to use physical device when trying to access camera